# Hide selected cell indicator from other users

Tags: google-sheets

When i shared a spreadsheet, i will see that if other users click on a cell , it will be higlighted in my end. I don't want to see this because it's quite annoying.

Is it possible to disable the highlight from other users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.                                                                                                                                                     _